# Single mysql select on one table, but sort a column twice both ASC and DESC?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a table of orders that have been placed. They are timestamped. Some orders are also flagged as priority orders.

Non-priority orders are filled FIFO - the oldest filled order is filled first, newer orders go to the back of the line.

However, there can be priority orders. These have a simple bool '1' on them to flag as priority. The thing is though, they are filled in reverse - newer priority orders push back older priority orders. So the timestamp on those is sorted DESC instead of ascending.

I basically need a select that works like this: (I know this isnt valid, I'm trying to show what I'm trying to achieve)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY priority DESC, 
(if priority = 1 order by timestamp DESC else order by timestamp)
```

I've tried unioning two selects, but those lose sorting. I tried (SELECT) UNION (SELECT) ORDER BY but I need the two different selects sorted differently.

Short of doing two separate selects - is this possible? I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this will work

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab ORDER BY    
(CASE WHEN 
 (priority = 1) THEN
        'timestamp DESC'
    ELSE
        'timestamp'
    END), priority DESC ;
```

See a demo fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ce7f/3

Comment: No. That is not what OP is expecting.

Comment: How come? see his posted query (one he tried) `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY priority DESC, (if priority = 1 order by timestamp DESC else order by timestamp`. In that case, the query posted is wrong!

Comment: your answer wont get compiled.

Comment: Yes, there was some mistake. Now it will.

Comment: That still doesnt seem to be working. When I run it, the entire case does not seem to work. I have a sample table, 2 columns, 'letter' and 'priority'. It has 9 rows, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, and h. Rows b, e, and g have prio 1. Using this:

Comment: Sorry, enter submitted the comment. Using this: select * from test order by (case when prio = 1 then 'letter desc' else 'letter' end), prio desc; just gives the table ordered by prio, and the desc is even ignored.

Comment: Well I found the answer, tried to answer it myself, and it wont let me because my rep is too low and it hasnt been 8 hours yet, so, eff it, and I'm not bothering. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN priority = 1 THEN 'timestamp DESC' ELSE 'timestamp ASC' END
```